# How to detect one single variable changed in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I use rxjs in angular 6

for example, there is one single variable,

```
let a = 1;
```

I want to excute any function when a is changed
I think rxjs could help my intent
help me how can i detect a when changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without RxJS, you can have `getter/setter` and use them to detect changes

```
private localA = 0;

public get a() {

}

public set a(value) { // new value assigned via this.a = 4

}
```

In the `setter a` you can detect any changes which are done with variable `localA`. You need just to work with `getter/setter a`

```
this.a = 5
```

This will run `public set a()` function and you can write your logic there.

### Example using `getter/setter` in ES6

```js
const obj = {
   localA: 4,
   get a() {
      return this.localA;
   },
   set a(value) {
      this.localA = value;
      console.log(`localA is changed to ${value}`);
   }
};

obj.a = 5;
obj.a = 6;
console.log(obj.a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a setter function

```js
private _a = 1;

public get a() {
    return this._a;
}

public set a(val) {
    this._a - val;
    // Do whatever you want in here
}
```

You can still access `a` as you would before, but whenever you set a value (`this.a = 2` for example) the setter will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Observables for this:

```
// Observable string sources

private variableUpdatedSource = new Subject<any>();

// Observable string streams

variableUpdated$ = this.variableUpdatedSource.asObservable();

// Message commands

updateVariable(data: any) {
  this.variableUpdatedSource.next(data);
}
```

when you want to update variable, just call 'updateVariable' function and when you want to get every update use subscribe ->

```
this.variableUpdated$.subscribe(data => { /* what to do with it? */ });
```

and if you want to get only one change, you could do this:

```
this.variableUpdated$.pipe(
  take(1),
  tap(data => { /* What do to with result */ })
).subscribe();
```